# how I can underline a contact or text when it is clicked using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The underline must be equal to the width of the contact

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient, underline

My website contacts are HOME ABOUT CONTACT ME. My website have a sticky bar at the top and contacts have in this bar, I want to underline height must be 2px. by the way, I also want to Shadow of sticky bar and background-color is gradient color. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What HTML have you written so far? You say your "*website contacts are*..." but what elements are those "contacts" nested within? When you tried to write your CSS, where did you get stuck? Please read (both) the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, and consider taking the [tour] to better understand how to use the site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your basic code to review and comment. You can add a div element or class element to your Contacts, and style the div/class element to following code. Suppose, your contacts is an anchor tag:

```html
<a href="#" class="contacts">Contacts</a>
```

CSS:

```html
a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
    
.contacts{
  line-height:2px;
}
```